# D3js, circle inside a circle (arc), unable to move inner circle using cx and cy

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So, I've been using this code as a base for the visualization I'm trying to create: https://bl.ocks.org/kgeorgiou/68f864364f277720252d0329408433ae

The idea basically is to add the circles inside the node's arc where it corresponds. And that's where I want *cx* and *cy* to move the inner circles to the appropriate position and then *transform* to take care of dispersing them (the transform part does work). But, the position of each of the circles don't move up or down (*cy* :( ). I know that the problem are not the values I'm calculating because I've also tried testing different values by harcoding them into the code to check what happens and the circle still doesn't move. I wonder if there is a problem when appending the circle to the nodeElement object.

```
function drawChildrenNodes(nodeElement, centroid, radius, cx, cy, options) {
var childrenNodeColor = getOptionOrDefault('childrenNodeColor', options);   
var innerWidth = getOptionOrDefault('innerWidth', options);

nodeElement.append("circle")
.attr("cx", cx)
.attr("cy", cy)
    .attr("r", radius-25)
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return childrenNodeColor;
    })
    .attr("stroke", function (d) {
        return 'black';
    })
    .attr("stroke-width", innerWidth)
   // .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + centroid + ")"; });

    console.log('hey listen!'+cy)
```

}

Attached is an example on how it's looking. I need those circles to move based on *cy* and *cx*. Please let me know if you see what I'm doing wrong or if you require more information to understand my problem.
Thank you !

[Visualization (network graph)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbyWu.png)

Comment: well, since, I'm new I cannot edit my questions.. But, just in case the circles that I'm trying to move are the inner circles (children). Also, forgot to add the image description, which it is basically a view on the visualization I'm getting.

Comment: other data that may help is that I'm editing the node-pie.js file.

Comment: something else that I'm reading is that the children may be inhering the parent's cx and cy positions so that's why they get centered. But, I don't find how to overwrite those positions... I would have expected that only adding the specific cx and cy positions would do that.

Comment: Your first comment is incorrect, all posters can edit their posts regardless of how new they are. There's an edit button just above these comments. You should really edit most of the other comments into your question and then delete all the comments.

Comment: Thank you Robert! I just saw it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the problem. It was actually inheriting the parent's position.
If you check the index.html there is a part where it is setting the circle's position (all the classes). So, I added the attribute class to the children circles and now I just need to add the position specifying the class:

```
d3.selectAll("circle.children").attr("cx", function (d) {
                        return d.x;
                    })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) {
                        return d.y;
                    });
```

Sorry for the noise. I'm still learning D3js :)